# nodejs downgraded from root using setuid, what about log file ownership?

Tags: node.js

I've roughly followed a scheme described in http://onteria.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/dropping-privileges-using-process-setuid-in-node-js/ whereby I start node as root, then downgrade the user. This way I can listen on 80 without the need for a proxy. Pretty standard stuff. I have an upstart script to manage the process (Ubuntu server).

The upstart script redirects stdout/err to a log file (which gets owned by root). Internally I'm using winston to log to the console and a file (which also gets owned by root).

In my perfect and happy world I would be able to transparently chown the log files (both the redirected stdout/err one and the one winston made) to the downgraded user. I've tried (naively) chowning them when I setuid'ed from inside the node app, which worked but meant that they never got written to again.

How can I achieve this? Is this possible or should I try to live with (at least some) log files owned by root?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more details about your attempt to chown? Why don't you chown/chmod the log files ahead of time, and then only write to them after dropping privileges? New files should be created as owned by the non-root user from then on, no?

Comment: The upstart script runs as root and does a redirect like `node app.js >> output.log 2>&1` so I don't think I can chown/chmod that guy ahead of time unless I give my user and root some group in common. The file that winston writes to I could initialize after dropping privileges, but that seems a bit hacky to me - it means that for some magic reason I can't log to that file anything that occurs prior to dropping privileges.

Comment: I was `chown`ing both files immediately after I'd bound to port 80 and immediately before `setuid`ing on the understanding I'd need to be root to do it.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for getting me to look a bit harder that. It turns out my original chown did (mostly) work! Both files are getting written to, except for the log statement immediately following the chown which is only written to stdout. I think I need to learn winston a bit better ...

Answer (score 1):

What I've ended up with is a version of Peter Lyons' solution (I've cut'n'pasted the following from a few places, so it may not actually run; the idea works, though):

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)();
logger.add(winston.transports.Console, {
  timestamp: true
});

// start server and downgrade user
httpsServer.listen(443, function() {
  logger.info('Ready on port 443');
  fs.stat(__filename, function(err, stats) {
    fs.chownSync('stdouterr.log',stats.uid,stats.gid);
    process.setgid(stats.gid);
    process.setuid(stats.uid);
    logger.add(winston.transports.File, { 
      filename: 'mylogfile.log',
      handleExceptions: true
    });
    logger.info('downgraded to non-root uid', {"uid":stats.uid});
  });
});
```

When I've successfully bound to port 443, I log to say that. `logger` is a winston logger configured with only console output (which gets redirected to the stdouterr.log file by starting node using `node app.js >> stdouterr.log 2>&1`). So this log message only appears on `stdouterr.log`.

Then I figure the owner of the current file and chown stdouterr.log to be owned by this user. Then I set the gid and uid of the current process (the dropping privileges part).

Then I add in my file logging to the winston logger.

Lastly, I log to say I've downgraded the user. This message appears in both `stdouterr.log` and `mylogfile.log`.

Not quite as beautiful as I'd hoped (no file logging while the process is running as root) but it means that the log files are easy to secure and manage.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Hopefully you don't need so much code executing before listening that you need log messages, but if you do, use straight stdio and you should be OK.